# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888 throw err; issue

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm working on a node express project. When I type nodemon server.js and the terminal showed the following error message. I deleted package-lock.json and node_modules folder and run npm install to try to solve this issue but it doesn't work. Does someone know how could I fix that?

```
wen-yikuo@Wen-YideMacBook-Pro Backend % nodemon server.js
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react'
Require stack:
- /Users/wen-yikuo/node_modules/recharts/lib/container/Surface.js
- /Users/wen-yikuo/node_modules/recharts/lib/index.js
- /Users/wen-yikuo/project_3/Backend/controllers/soldierController.js
- /Users/wen-yikuo/project_3/Backend/routes/soldierRoutes.js
- /Users/wen-yikuo/project_3/Backend/app.js
- /Users/wen-yikuo/project_3/Backend/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wen-yikuo/node_modules/recharts/lib/container/Surface.js:8:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/wen-yikuo/node_modules/recharts/lib/container/Surface.js',
    '/Users/wen-yikuo/node_modules/recharts/lib/index.js',
    '/Users/wen-yikuo/project_3/Backend/controllers/soldierController.js',
    '/Users/wen-yikuo/project_3/Backend/routes/soldierRoutes.js',
    '/Users/wen-yikuo/project_3/Backend/app.js',
    '/Users/wen-yikuo/project_3/Backend/server.js'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.2",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVDOT.png)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems `react` is missing from your dependencies, so:

`npm import react`

should do the trick.

If that's not it, I suspect it's an issue with one of these being missing or misspelled in your `app.js`:

```
const soldierRoutes = require('./routes/soldierRoutes');
const soldierController = require('./controllers/soldierController');
```

and/or one of the `module.exports` in those other files.